# Convert rows to lowercase in node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm currently using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) to query my DB like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM users.names ORDER BY name;
```

I want to return the lowercase of these names, so I've tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(lower(name)) FROM users.names ORDER BY lower(name);
```

...but this just returns `null` in place of each name.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LOWER(tag)) AS tag FROM support.tags ORDER BY LOWER(tag);
```

The key addition is obviously `AS tag`, otherwise the 'tag' field was renamed to 'lower' in the results set.